# Creating IDs for uniqueness and URL referentiality

Tags: url, uuid

I need to create objects and make them available on the web. Similarly to stackoverflow, I have something like.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/78374
```

However, in my case the ID of the object I create must be unique, so I am thinking about a UUID, leading to a URL like

```
http://example.com/users/{8e931066-7d87-4f2b-a3b5-608c4c9a9083}
```

because later on I will have to merge different databases together, and I don't want to have merging issues.

Is this an accepted practice? What are the alternatives?

Comment: I'm guessing just an auto-increment for user IDs would cause problems with the merge at a later date that you mentioned?

Comment: yes, an autoincrement would be a problem because merging would mean that user 234241 would become, say 452467 when merged. using uuid, that user would be 8e931066-7d87-4f2b-a3b5-608c4c9a9083 in any case. SO and the others use the first technique I guess, but the situation in my case is a bit more complex than that (I am not dealing with users, and I also have revisions a la wikipedia)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's just a question of merging databases, giving each db a unique identifier and then combining that with the auto-increment PK would give unique ids for every object you could use and not worry about merging issues.

Comment: I think this is the right approach. Using UUIDs is overkill. URLs is something that users see; they need to be short and simple if possible.

Comment: but that would mean that the IDs will change at the merge

Comment: I've merged some by just adding 10,000 to the second databases' IDs, and then adjusted my sequences.  In one case, where I've got a sort of  materialized view into two databases that are still growing, one of 'em is multiplied by `-1` before merging.  But in cases like this, you just have two columns in the merged table, with the naming authority and the assigned number as the primary key.

Comment: @StefanoBorini: if you are merging two separate databases, chances are those were two separate systems referenced by two separate URLs. In this case, the URLs of some objects would change anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in that. Hotmail does that.

Answer (score 1):

If merging must be 100% seamless, then a UUID is probably your best bet.  If you are looking to generate more human-friendly URL's, you may consider using a unique "Account Name" that the user can define.  This would potentially create conflicts if merging databases, but they can be overcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that this is an acceptable practice because it keeps the user ID unique when using it over multiple databases and applications.

I use the same practice in my caching application block.  The caching application block generates a GUID when an item is cached and the application uses that GUID to retrieve the item from the cache.